# NSRangeException happening only on device but not in simulator

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, xcode8

The app crashes on device but not in simulator. The xcode(8.2.1) console is not showing much info.

It is crashing before `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` method, so I am unable to debug it.

This is the complete stacktrace

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 9 beyond bounds [0 ..
>   8]'
>   *** First throw call stack: (0x18f8251b8 0x18e25c55c 0x18f7007f4 0x195e803a0 0x195beb928 0x195a1db58 0x195a1dd88 0x195a0b320
>   0x195a22dec 0x1957bede8 0x1956d7a80 0x192b859d8 0x192b7a4cc
>   0x192b7a38c 0x192af73e0 0x192b1ea68 0x192b1f488 0x18f7d20c0
>   0x18f7cfcf0 0x18f6fe2d8 0x1957457b0 0x195740534 0x1001492fc
>   0x18e6e15b8) libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of
>   type NSException

I have added the symbolic breakpoint for objectAtIndex.
All the time it hits at:

```
CoreFoundation`-[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]:
->  0x18f70073c <+0>:   adrp   x8, 148294
```

and it crashes after I contnue/step over multiple times.

Why it is happening on device but not on simulator ?

Comment: do you find out why it doesn't happen in simulator?

Answer (score 0):

I removed the pods_appName.framework from Link Binary with Libraries section, and crash is not happening after that.

I am still surprised why it didn't crash all these days!